# Windows Driver Kit, light version?

Tags: windows, wdk

The program [Notepad2-mod](http://github.com/XhmikosR/notepad2-mod) can only be built using Windows Driver Kit (WDK) or Intel C++ Compiler (ICL).

The ICL is not free as I can see, and the WDK appears to be a [1 GB download](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852362).

Is a smaller version of the WDK available?

Comment: The Notepad2-mod site says WDK 7.1, which is "only" 620MB, if that's any help (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11800) or you could try Visual C++ 2010 Express (http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-express-windows-desktop) although that's a web installer so I'm not sure what the total download size is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using
[this script](http://github.com/svnpenn/a/blob/f4890e7/misc/baby-wdk.sh),
I downloaded the WDK and extracted only that which I need

- `buildtools`
- `headers`
- `libs`

I uploaded this
[subset of the WDK](http://bitbucket.org/svnpenn/a/downloads)
to Bitbucket, final size 52 MB.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the "Build" directory, there's a script for building with VS2010 and VS2012.